# Mysql request from two tables advanced2

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables:

```
**tbl_questions**
id user_id title  solved_answer
1  1       Title1 0               // Not solved question
2  2       Title2 3               // Solved question

**tbl_answers**
id user_id title   
1  3       Answer1 
2  4       Answer2 
3  4       Answer3
```

I need to calculate number of questions with solved answers by user_id = 4

How can I do this?

Comment: What's the link between tbl_questions and tbl_answers? how do you know for which question is Answer1 solved in tbl_answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return all solved answers (taking into consideration that you update the question with the id of the answer from the answers table)

```
select * from question q
join answer a on q.solved_answer = a.id
```

This one will search for the answer of a specific question with a specific user:

```
select * from question q
join answer a on q.solved_answer = a.id
where a.user_id=4
```